# ggplot2: display one group with a line and another group with points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix like this:

```
    names        x        y    group
1       1   -0.050    -0.76        2
2       2    0.040    -0.36        2
3       3    0.060    -0.28        2
4       4    0.080    -0.22        1
5       5    0.080    -0.14        1
6       6    0.040    -0.26        1
7       7    0.030    -0.36        1
```

I am trying to make a graph with `ggplot2`, but I would like to represent one group with a line and the other group with points. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
geom_point(data=df[df$group==2, ])+
geom_line(data=df[df$group==1, ])
```

data

```
df <- dput(df)
structure(list(names = 1:7, x = c(-0.05, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.04, 0.03), y = c(-0.76, -0.36, -0.28, -0.22, -0.14, -0.26, 
-0.36), group = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("names", 
"x", "y", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```